# AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'ManyToMany'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to make one of my `model` objects a `ManyToMany` Field, so I can access the objects through both models.

I am receiving the following `error`.

```
listing = models.ManyToMany(Listings, blank=True, related_name="listing")
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'ManyToMany'
```

`models.py`:

```py
class WatchList(models.Model):
    listing = models.ManyToMany(Listings, blank=True, related_name="listing")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
```

Comment: It is `ManyToManyField`, not `ManyToMany`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the field is a [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField), so this includes the `…Field` in `ManyToManyField`:

```
from django.conf import settings

class WatchList(models.Model):
    listing = models.ManyToManyField(Listings, blank=True, related_name='watchlists')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `Listings` model to the `Watchlist`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`listing`</s> relation to `watchlists`.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `listing` instead of <s>`listings`</s>.